# What is a good way to remind someone to reply to your email?

Tags: word-choice, meaning, email

Sometimes some of the emails to people senior to you in the company are left unanswered.

What are the ways to politely remind the person that he needs to reply to your email (which he might have missed/forgotten about)?

I once used this as a reply to the sent mail

> Please let me know about this when you
>   get a chance.

I had picked this up from somewhere and am not sure how exactly it conveys the message.

Comment: I'll type out a full answer when I get the chance, but let me quickly say here that "Please let me know about this when you get a chance," could be informal, at best. But this really depends on the nature of the professional relationship. Sometimes you email your boss so often that you begin ignore salutations and the like.

Comment: The only way I know to express this is "I am looking forward to hearing from you".... I do not know other expressions. Good question.

Comment: [workplace.se] might be a better place to ask this question. It's more about workplace social issues than language.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be moved to workplace (where it's possibly a duplicate).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It depends on what the relationship is like with the recipient. If you are fairly friendly you can be less formal.

Assuming you include the e-mail you are referring to in some way, you might say:

> Have you had a chance to look at this yet?

This informally conveys the sense that you know how busy they are.

For a more formal version you would probably want to write it as a full e-mail:

> John/Sir/Whatever you'd normally say
>
> I was wondering if you have had a chance to look at the e-mail below yet? [Give a reason] Our customer enquired about it earlier today.
>
> Many thanks,
>
> Bob

Comment: The second phrase (I was wondering...) is not really a question.

Answer (score 12):

Dear / Hi John (Use "Dear" or "Hi" depending on how professional your relationship is)

In regards to our recent correspondence as seen in the email trail below, please would you be so kind to let me have your feedback?

Your assistance herein is greatly appreciated. OR Id like to close finalise this matter and your feedback will be of great assistance.

Kind regards,

Ipsum Consult Team

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a question mark; it implies impatience, frustration etc.  I would say Just a quick reminder about your ***_*__**; thank you very much.

Comment: I think the question mark is a good idea as it invites the recipient to give a quick reply - which may range from the curt "No, not yet" to the more helpful "I haven't had chance yet but will do so by the end of the week" or similar. Either of those is an improvement on silence as they at least acknowledge receipt.